# Android set wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am using `WallpaperManager` to set an image as wallpaper.

The problem is that the image is automatically enlarged and set ( ie the entire image doesnt appear on screen).

I have tried

- setting very small images,
- also have tried scaling down images and setting them, but none of them works.

It seems the image is scaled and set.

Is there any way to resolve this??

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: There is no error or exception in the code. You can look at the output in http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/setting-an-image-as-a-wallpaper/      I am getting that output but as you can see the wallpaper set is not same as the image. The whole image is not there in the wallpaper it gets cropped  and enlarged, whereas I want the full image to be set as the wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to scale your images.